# How to annotate generator functions in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, generator

Let's look at the example `async` function from [promisejs.org](https://www.promisejs.org/generators/), which is allows us to wait for promises using generators:

```
function async(makeGenerator){
  return function () {
    var generator = makeGenerator.apply(this, arguments);

    function handle(result){
      // result => { done: [Boolean], value: [Object] }
      if (result.done) return Promise.resolve(result.value);

      return Promise.resolve(result.value).then(function (res){
        return handle(generator.next(res));
      }, function (err){
        return handle(generator.throw(err));
      });
    }

    try {
      return handle(generator.next());
    } catch (ex) {
      return Promise.reject(ex);
    }
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
var login = async(function* (username, password, session) {
  var user = yield getUser(username);
  var hash = yield crypto.hashAsync(password + user.salt);
  if (user.hash !== hash) {
    throw new Error('Incorrect password');
  }
  session.setUser(user);
});
```

**My question:** How should both of these functions be annotated in TypeScript, in orded to keep type safety?

**What I've tried:**
I know the `async` function returns a `Promise<T>`, but I'm not sure what `T` should be. I guess it should depend on the generator passed in, but what type does a generator have? There is `GeneratorFunction` in the typings for nodejs or bluebird (can't remember which), but that one is not generic so I can't do `async(makeGenerator: GeneratorFunction<T>): Promise<T>` as I'd want to.

Comment: You shouldn't use these in Typescript at all. Just go for `async`/`await` right away!

Comment: Have you tried to annotate the types? Where was the problem? Please show us your effort.

Comment: @Bergi async/await doesn't seem to be supported by NodeJS yet. I've tried some few annotations but none seemed to work; I omitted them for brevity because they all felt stupid. But I can add some of them to show my work, sure.

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's not supported by Node - [it's supported by TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/release-notes/typescript-1.7.html)! Isn't that the whole reason you're using a transpiler?

Comment: @Bergi Oh, this is new information! I have to check this out. But I think there still might be use cases here so the question is still relevant. And I've added some examples of what I've tried.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2873 seems to hold the relevant discussion, though I cannot exactly figure out what their result is. In any case, I think your type is `function async(makeGenerator:(...*) -> Iterable<T>): (...*) -> Promise<T>`, and typescript's type system will not allow you to express any more advanced.

Comment: That seems to be the closest to an answer that I'm getting, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

> but I'm not sure what T should be

In your case `login` returns nothing to `Promise<void>`.

Comment: But the async function could potentially be used with other kinds of generator functions, so how do i express that in typescript? The type in the promise should be the same as the type in the generator, but how does a generator type annotation look like?